# jQuery UI - How to disable sort on child drag

Tags: jquery-ui

[image]

I would like to disable sort when user drag red box.

How I can do this?

```
$(function() {
    $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    });
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfz57cqs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was searching for a solution for the same problem – and found it. It's easy: you need to add a `cancel` attribute to the instantiation of sortable:

```
$(function() {
    $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        cancel: '.no-drag'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks  for solution !